# If $\mathcal{B}(A,E)$ is banach then $E$ is banach ($A$ is a set)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider $\mathcal{B}(A,E)$ the space of bounded functions from $A$ to $E$ where $A$ is a **set** and $E$ a linear normed vector space. I need to proof that if $\mathcal{B}(A,E)$ is Banach then $E$ is Banach.
I found proofs of this in the case that $A$ is also a linear normed vector space, and those proofs involved linear functionals. But given a Cauchy sequence in $E$ how can I construct a **function** from the set $A$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try realizing $E$ as a (closed) subspace of $\mathcal{B}(A, E)$.

Comment: @user125932 thanks! I am going to give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant functions form a closed subspace of $\mathcal{B}(A,E)$ isometric to $E$.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to elaborate

Comment: If $x_n$ is Cauchy in $E$. Define $f_n: A \to E: f_n(a) = x_n$...

Comment: thanks. For proving the isometric part, is that as trivial as saying for a given $e\in E$ take $f:A\to E$ such that $f(x)=e$ for all $x\in A$ ??

Comment: @mate89 Yes, call that constant map $f: A \to E$, $F(e) \in \mathcal{B}(A,E)$ and note that $\|F(e) - F(e')\|_\infty = \|e-e'\|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Finally, for proving this set is closed, can you confirm this idea of proof is correct?:  given a convergent sequence of functions $f_n$ in that space of constant functions, we have for a given $\varepsilon > 0$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < ||f_n-f||_\infty < \varepsilon$ for all $x\in E$, but this is the same as a sequence $(e_n)$ in E that should converge to a point $e$ and by uniqueness of limit $f(x) = e$

Comment: @mate89 that's roughly correct indeed.

Comment: @mate89 $f_n \to f$, where $f_n \equiv e_n$ then $e_n$ is Cauchy as $\|e_n - e_m\| = \|f_n -f_m\|_\infty$. So $e_n$ converges to some $e \in E$. Then $f_n$ converges to the constant function with value $e$, so $f \in F[A]$ too.